# Azure B2C Custom Attribute Graph API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to read custom attributes through the graph API.

Using the Azure.Identity 1.5 package and Microsoft.Graph v4 package.

```
var selects = $"givenName,surName,displayName,identities,mail,mobilePhone,{B2CHelper.GetCompleteAttributeName("mfaType")},{B2CHelper.GetCompleteAttributeName("IsEnterprise")}";
var values = await _graphServiceClient.Users[id].Request()
    .Select(selects)
    .GetAsync();

var mfaType = values.AdditionalData[B2CHelper.GetCompleteAttributeName("mfaType")]; 
var isEnterprise = values.AdditionalData[B2CHelper.GetCompleteAttributeName("IsEnterprise")];
```

This Throws an error stating its not in the dictionary.

Here is my helper function that builds the custom attribute.

```
      internal static string GetCompleteAttributeName(string attributeName)
      {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attributeName))
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null", nameof(attributeName));
        }

        return $"extension_{_b2cExtensionAppClientId}_{attributeName}";
     }
```

No matter what I try from examples I find. They do not come back. I'm not even sure what they look like when they come back. I've looked in the additional data, and it just lists the fields. Can't really find examples for this using the newer Azure.Identity pacakge.

Comment: You can get all user's properties with `...Request().Select("*")...`. Then check the property's name that match the name generated by `GetCompleteAttributeName`.

Comment: That doesn't work for custom/extension attributes.

Comment: What is the value given to `_b2cExtensionAppClientId`? You may need to remove the hyphens inside the raw GUID

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the extension property names are case sensitive.